created / installed npm package, getting 'unexpected token' error when trying to import and use in Playwright
I have checked the similar questions, but many of them seem specific to use Typescript.  However, in our environment, we're using Javascript.
So we have a simple file of functions (functions.js), which has been published as a scoped package in our internal system.
export Class Functions {
//  functions here 
} 

Then in index.js, I have
export { Functions } from "./Functions"

And in the package.json, we have
main: 'index.js'
type: 'commonjs'

When I try to use it in our Playwright tests, if I import it like this:
const { Functions } = require{'@qa/functions')

Playwright shows an error, "unexpected token export" and it references the index.js file.
I also see an additional error "could not find a declaration file, typescript error 7016).   I'm a bit confused since we are not using typescript at all in this environment.

To use export,  don't you need to use type: "module" in your package.json? module.exports is the commonjs version, so you're mixing two paradigms. Generally, use import/export modules, especially if you're using npx playwright test to run your tests, which should work with modules just fine. If this isn't TS, and doesn't really pertain to actually using Playwright, I'd remove those tags, although the context isn't a bad thing to mention in general.

If the dupe doesn't solve the problem, please clarify how you're running Playwright and provide enough info to repro the problem, and let us know which of the two paradigms you actually want to use. Thanks.

We're using playwright running it locally using 'npx playwright test'  All our current tests are using
const {  xxxx } = require(",,/../xxx.js')

So re-reading your message. from what I understand, in my functions file, it should be
class Functions {
// functions here 
} 
//then a line at end 
module.exports = { Functions }

and in the index.js
module.exports = { Functions} 

??

Sure, if you're using commonjs it's require and module.exports. But probably use modules, import and export. Choose one or the other. BTW to code format markdown in comments use single backticks without spaces around the code.
